# Edit an existing app detail page icon or image?

Tags: facebook

How do you change an app detail image or icon?  There is no delete or upload button once you already have uploaded an image to the app detail page(unsbumitted state).  There is no way to remove it or change it so you are stuck with it? help?! Tried in safari and chrome...no luck.

Answer (score 0):

On mouse hover the image, you will see the Edit link

[image]